# How can I run a list of async processes when some items are dependent on each other?

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, twisted, process

I have a list of dynamically generated processes (command line libraries with arguments) which I need to run.

I know that some of them are dependent on each other. I already have some objects which contain this information. For example, standalone_exec_item contains process_data.process_id and also dependent_on_process_ids (which is a list of process ids.)

Currently I am thinking of using the multiprocessing library to run the list of processes asynchronously sort of like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess

def execute_standalone_exec_items(standalone_exec_items):

        standalones = []

        def run_command(command):
            output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(command))
            return output

        for standalone_exec_item in standalone_exec_items:
            standalone_command = generate_command(standalone_exec_item.process_data)

            standalone = Process(
                target=run_command,
                args=(standalone_command,)
            )
            standalones.append(standalone)

        for standalone in standalones:
            standalone.start()

        while True:
            flag = True
            for standalone in standalones:
                if standalone.is_alive():
                    flag = False
            if flag:
                break
```

However I want to know if there's a nicer way of waiting for the asynchronous processes to run before running the dependent processes. Can I use callbacks? I've heard about Twisted's deferred, can I use this?

What's the best practice?

Edit:
Is it correct that Popen is non-blocking and I don't need to use multiprocessing? Or do I need to use fcntl()?

Comment: The main difference Twisted will make is to give you a simple alternative to the busy loop at the end of your function.  This will make your program use significantly less CPU while achieving the same results.  You'll still have to implement the logic for running the correct processes at the right time, though.

Comment: I would say look into module `multiprocessing.queues`. If your Problem transferred into consumer-producer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a message queue, where some process publishing message(s) which the to be called process will subscribe.